# Como pegar o tamanho de uma janela externa

Tags: delphi, windows, api

No meu caso tem uma aplicação que roda paralelo a um aplicativo de terceiro qual não tenho acesso ao fonte, preciso que meu programa capture o tamanho desta janela para exibir um form do mesmo tamanho na mesma posição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou passar o básico para você implementar, primeiro precisamos descobrir qual o Handle da aplicação:

```
var
hWindow : THandle;
begin
    hWindow := FindWindow(nil, 'Calculadora');
end;
```

Com isso podemos obter as posições para sobrepor sua aplicação:

```
var
Left, Top, Width, Height: Word;
begin
     GetWindowRect(hWindow, R);
     Left := R.Left;
     Top := R.Top;
     Width := R.Right - R.Left;
     Height := R.Bottom - R.Top;
end;
```

E depois mover a aplicação para o tamanho do seu form:

```
Windows.MoveWindow(hWindow, Form1.ClientHeight, Form1.ClientWidth, r.right-r.left,r.bottom-r.top, true);
```

Tente implementar isso em seu aplicativo, e faça as alterações necessárias.

Comment: muito obrigado amigo.